# Making a div transparent and showing background image

Tags: html, css

I want to make the div transparent in a way, that the background image could be seen through it. All online tutorials seem to work, but seems like I miss some detail in the project that matters.

CSS:

```
html {
    background: url('../images/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}

div.container-fluid{
    /*-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";         */
    /*filter: alpha(opacity=0);   */
    /*-moz-opacity: 0.0;           */
    /*-khtml-opacity: 0.0;         */
    /*opacity: 0.0;                */
    /*background: rgba(255,255,255,0);*/
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>M</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Cue"/>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="" class="header-text">M</a>
            <h1>M</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <main>

            </main>
        </div>
     </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Your code's working for me. Can you be more specific about what's not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in bootstrap there is body `background:#fff;`, you can add to body background:transparent;

Comment: That's indeed the case - does not seem to be very intuitive. Why is this done this way? :)

Comment: It will be better if you give background with image to body or to some div, not to html.

Comment: Yes, I did that as well :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working (see demo) - I added a red-border on the `H1` for reference.  Maybe I misunderstood your issue?

Bootstrap does have its own background colour settings.  You may want to override those if you are going to use it.

```css
html {
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/g/500/500') no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}

div.container-fluid{
    /*-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";         */
    /*filter: alpha(opacity=0);   */
    /*-moz-opacity: 0.0;           */
    /*-khtml-opacity: 0.0;         */
    /*opacity: 0.0;                */
    /*background: rgba(255,255,255,0);*/
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="" class="header-text">M</a>
            <h1>M</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <main>

            </main>
        </div>
     </div>
```